# Anyone know a good freeware sql script generator?

Tags: sql-server, sql-scripts

I have found this one:

http://www.sqlscriptgenerator.com/

Which is actually decent enough but it puts all the scripts in one massive sql script file with no option to generate one script per object.

Is there something that will allow me to generate a suite of scripts that I can then pass into a source control repository and update from time to time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server Management Studio will do this for you. You can also choose to script out data as well.

All you have to do is to right-click on a database, choose Tasks then Generate Scripts...

You also have the option of writing everything to a single file, or a file per object.

Comment: What in a sort of "fire and forget" make me a whole stack of scripts to this directory sort of way? Which button do I press!?

Comment: @One Monkey - Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: I know I can go through each table and individually generate a CREATE script for each table but I clearly am not aware of how to just get SSMS to dump the create scripts for an entire DB to a directory of my choosing or I would have done it already. So where can I find this option in SMSS? Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, found it: Right click the database, choose "Generate Scripts..." thanks. How useful.